Show application logcat messages in Run Console - Android Studio 2023+
I recently downloaded the Koala Android Studio. I would like to view application logcat messages in the Run Console. It seems this functinality is no longer available...
On the Chipmunk Android Studio, I still have this option. Is there a way it can be enabled in later versions of Android studio?

